# DirectX Shader not working right?

Tags: c++, directx, shader, hlsl, occlusion

Okay so I have this shader for ambient occlusion. It loads to world correctly, but it just shows all the models as being white. I do not know why. I am just running the shader while the model is rendering, is that correct? or do I need to make a render target or something? if so then how? I'm using C++. Here is my shader.

```
float sampleRadius;
float distanceScale;
float4x4 xProjection;
float4x4 xView;
float4x4 xWorld;

float3 cornerFustrum;

struct VS_OUTPUT
{
    float4 pos              : POSITION;
    float2 TexCoord         : TEXCOORD0;
    float3 viewDirection    : TEXCOORD1;
}; 

VS_OUTPUT VertexShaderFunction(
    float4 Position : POSITION, float2 TexCoord : TEXCOORD0)
{
    VS_OUTPUT Out = (VS_OUTPUT)0;

    float4 WorldPosition = mul(Position, xWorld);
    float4 ViewPosition = mul(WorldPosition, xView);
    Out.pos = mul(ViewPosition, xProjection);
    Position.xy = sign(Position.xy);
    Out.TexCoord = (float2(Position.x, -Position.y) + float2( 1.0f, 1.0f ) ) * 0.5f;
    float3 corner = float3(-cornerFustrum.x * Position.x,
            cornerFustrum.y * Position.y, cornerFustrum.z);
    Out.viewDirection =  corner;

    return Out;
}


texture depthTexture;
texture randomTexture;

sampler2D depthSampler = sampler_state
{
    Texture = <depthTexture>;
    ADDRESSU = CLAMP;
    ADDRESSV = CLAMP;
    MAGFILTER = LINEAR;
    MINFILTER = LINEAR;
};

sampler2D RandNormal = sampler_state
{
    Texture = <randomTexture>;
    ADDRESSU = WRAP;
    ADDRESSV = WRAP;
    MAGFILTER = LINEAR;
    MINFILTER = LINEAR;
};

float4 PixelShaderFunction(VS_OUTPUT IN) : COLOR0
{
    float4 samples[16] =
    {
        float4(0.355512,    -0.709318,  -0.102371,  0.0 ),
        float4(0.534186,    0.71511,    -0.115167,  0.0 ),
        float4(-0.87866,    0.157139,   -0.115167,  0.0 ),
        float4(0.140679,    -0.475516,  -0.0639818, 0.0 ),
        float4(-0.0796121,  0.158842,   -0.677075,  0.0 ),
        float4(-0.0759516,  -0.101676,  -0.483625,  0.0 ),
        float4(0.12493,     -0.0223423, -0.483625,  0.0 ),
        float4(-0.0720074,  0.243395,   -0.967251,  0.0 ),
        float4(-0.207641,   0.414286,   0.187755,   0.0 ),
        float4(-0.277332,   -0.371262,  0.187755,   0.0 ),
        float4(0.63864,     -0.114214,  0.262857,   0.0 ),
        float4(-0.184051,   0.622119,   0.262857,   0.0 ),
            float4(0.110007,    -0.219486,  0.435574,   0.0 ),
        float4(0.235085,    0.314707,   0.696918,   0.0 ),
        float4(-0.290012,   0.0518654,  0.522688,   0.0 ),
        float4(0.0975089,   -0.329594,  0.609803,   0.0 )
    };

    IN.TexCoord.x += 1.0/1600.0;
    IN.TexCoord.y += 1.0/1200.0;

    normalize (IN.viewDirection);
    float depth = tex2D(depthSampler, IN.TexCoord).a;
    float3 se = depth * IN.viewDirection;

    float3 randNormal = tex2D( RandNormal, IN.TexCoord * 200.0 ).rgb;

    float3 normal = tex2D(depthSampler, IN.TexCoord).rgb;
    float finalColor = 0.0f;

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        float3 ray = reflect(samples[i].xyz,randNormal) * sampleRadius;

        //if (dot(ray, normal) < 0)
        //  ray += normal * sampleRadius;

        float4 sample = float4(se + ray, 1.0f);
        float4 ss = mul(sample, xProjection);

        float2 sampleTexCoord = 0.5f * ss.xy/ss.w + float2(0.5f, 0.5f);

        sampleTexCoord.x += 1.0/1600.0;
        sampleTexCoord.y += 1.0/1200.0;
        float sampleDepth = tex2D(depthSampler, sampleTexCoord).a;

        if (sampleDepth == 1.0)
        {
            finalColor ++;
        }
        else
        {       
            float occlusion = distanceScale* max(sampleDepth - depth, 0.0f);
            finalColor += 1.0f / (1.0f + occlusion * occlusion * 0.1);
        }
    }

    return float4(finalColor/16, finalColor/16, finalColor/16, 1.0f);
}


technique SSAO
{
    pass P0
    {          
        VertexShader = compile vs_3_0 VertexShaderFunction();
        PixelShader  = compile ps_3_0 PixelShaderFunction();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem can come from lot of different things, some code to show how you call you shader would come in handy. Also those screen space AO shaders are normally post processing ones, so they should be called after your scene has been rendered.

Comment: Yeah that actually sounds right now. Thanks!

Comment: Is your question answered yet? Then please post an own answer for completion this question.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the core question: this shader is for render target processing -- you need the depth buffer to be filled before running it. It's not for rendering on the model surfaces.